# FFMPEG audio and video frames not maching each others?

Tags: ffmpeg, console-application, h.264, screen-capture, aac

I am trying to use FFMPEG console tools effectively. Now I can record video and audio same time but my issue audio is delaying. I use following code:

```
C:\Users\gomid_000\Desktop\ffmpeg.exe -y -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -f gdigrab -show_region 1 -framerate 60 -i desktop -map 0 -map 1 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\Users\gomid_000\Desktop\out.mp4 -threads:1 4
```

Update : Frames were duplicating, indeed it was not ready for intel qsv, I use h264 now. I updated it like this following code delay is fixed a bit but frame performance is reduced now I need options to reduce performance drop also:

```
C:\Users\gomid_000\Desktop\ffmpeg.exe -y -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -c:a aac -f gdigrab -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -qp 0 -pix_fmt yuv444p -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 0 -maxrate 1M -bufsize 2M -vf mpdecimate -r 15 -threads:4 4 "C:\Users\gomid_000\Desktop\recording-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-Hmss).mp4"
```

1. What should I do to use aac and h264_qsv codec together ?
2. Which improvments can I do to prevend audio or video delay ?

Answer (score 0):

This [FFmpeg documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow) shows many examples about using DirectShow, and especially a section about latency and buffering should be interesting to you.
Further down, there is also an extra link to recording the screen on Windows.

Without having access to your PC it is hard to say which combo of commands exactly would work for you, so it would be purely guessing.

Best have a look at the link and fiddle around with it until finding the combination that works in your case. Which unfortunately is standard FFmpeg procedure in many cases that depend a lot on circumstances ;)

Comment: For directshow registered device needed. I have no video capture card and I have no device listed for screen what to do ? Which device to use ?

Comment: Like everytime I did, not readed instructions again. I switched dshow with uscreencapture and had same frame issues but there says you will modify it  by registry, now that is fixed.